# Using a non-static class member inside a comparison function

Tags: c++, class, static, sorting, functor

I'm currently developing a syntaxic analyser class that needs, at a point of the code, to sort structs holding info about operators. Each operator has a priority, which is user-defined through public member functions of my analyser class. Thus, when sorting, I need my sorting function to order elements based on the priority of the corresponding operator. I'm using the following code to compare elements:

```
bool parser::op_comp(const op_info& o1, const op_info& o2) {
    op_def& op1 = operators[o1.op_char];
    op_def& op2 = operators[o2.op_char];

    return op1.priority > op2.priority;
}
```

Note that I had to make this function static, since it's defined inside of a class.

In fact, my compare function compares elements of type `op_char`, and I retrieve the operator def from a map which contain elements of type `op_def`, which have a field "priority".

The problem I'm facing is that I can't manage to use `std::sort(ops.begin(), ops.end(), std::mem_fun_ref(&parser::op_comp))` (where ops is a `vector of op_info)` method. I get the following error, which sounds quite logical :

error: invalid use of member `parser::operators' in static member function

Here is my question : how can I force std::sort to use a comp function that makes use of elements from non-static members of the class ? Obviously the function should be non-static, but I can't manage to use it if I don't make it static...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a functor instead of a function:

```
struct op_comp : std::binary_function<op_info, op_info, bool>
    {
    op_comp(parser * p) : _parser(p) {}
    bool operator() (const op_info& o1, const op_info& o2) {
        return _parser->op_comp(o1, o2);
    }
    parser * _parser;
};
```

This way the method `op_comp` can stay non-static. However the caller needs an instance of the parser, where are all the operators are stored. This is the usage of our new functor:

```
std::sort(ops.begin(), ops.end(), op_comp(&my_parser));
```

Where `my_parser` is the instance of parser you are using. Alternatively, if you are calling `std::sort` from the parser, you can simply write:

```
std::sort(ops.begin(), ops.end(), op_comp(this));
```

Answer (score 5):

Make operators static as well, and you'll be able to use it in op_comp.

Alternatively, use a functor instead of a function:

```
class myCompareClass {
  public:
  bool operator() (
    const op_info& o1, const op_info& o2) { 
    op_def& op1 = operators[o1.op_char]; 
    op_def& op2 = operators[o2.op_char]; 

    return op1.priority > op2.priority; 
  }
  private:
    ... operators ...
} myCompareObject;

std::sort(ops.begin(), ops.end(), myCompareObject)
```

See more examples at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

Comment: Thank you! Yet my problem is that the content of `operators` is dependent on which instance of `parser` I'm dealing with.

Another solution, I realized, was also to simply copy the "priority" information to each op_info object when creating such an object.

I'm very impressed by how fast and good answers are, and by how nice the people are, on this website. Thank you!

Comment: this is a very nice solution! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you want op_comp to be non-static you can use Boost.Lambda or Boost.Bind:

```
parser my_parser;
sort(ops.begin(), ops.end(), bind(&parser::op_comp, ref(my_parser)));
```

Comment: +1. Use TR1 `std::tr1::bind` if available; otherwise `boost::bind`.