# How to use a non-static member function in Hasher?

Tags: c++, hash, static-methods

I need to establish a hash table using a hasher different from the default one, so I write something like:

```
class foo {
public:
...
private:
  struct myhasher {
    size_t operator() (myclass bar) { return hash_calculation bar; }
  }
  static size_t hash_calculation (myclass bar) {
    // do some calculation
  }
  hash_map<myclass, myhasher> myhashmap;
}
```

It works. Now for some reason I have to write a non-static member function to replace hash_calculation, say, it needs a non-static member of the class as an argument. Then the whole thing failed because I cannot use a non-static method in a nested struct.

This is somehow similar to another widely discussed problem: how to use a non-static function to do comparison or sorting. See for example:
[Using a non-static class member inside a comparison function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731404/using-a-non-static-class-member-inside-a-comparison-function)
and
[C++ std list sort with custom comparator that depends on an member variable for the object instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372918/c-std-list-sort-with-custom-comparator-that-depends-on-an-member-variable-for) . They both established a functor instead of a function as the comparator. However in my case this trick does not work because I need a class name inside the hash_map definition, not a specific struct object.  What should I do? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: By this return hash_calculation bar; did you mean this return hash_calculation(bar);?

Comment: There is no `hash_map` class template in standard C++.  Did you mean `std::unordered_map`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. How is the `hash_map` supposed to know which instance of `myhasher` should be used when calling `myhaser::hash_calculation`?

`hash_map` isn't part of the standard C++ library, not even in C++11, so it's a custom class, and you have included no information about how it works. If there is a way for it to take some sort of constructor argument for which `myhasher` it should use, you're in luck. But it doesn't sound like it.

Also, you're using pass by value when you probably mean to pass in a const reference. Passing by value is likely going to be really slow and inefficient.

Comment: @DavidM: Editing your original question to be more accurate would prevent that issue from being a distraction to people who answer it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The standard "hash-map", i.e., `std::unordered_map<K, V, H, E, A>` takes a hash object of type `H` as constructor argument. A copy of this object is used to determine the hash for the object by way of the function call operator. This way can provide some context. Obviously, you were already using a non-static function call operator but you choose to delegate to a static member.